# Keeping the same scale across different heatmaps

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure

I plot heatmaps using subsets of a dataset. I wish to compare different heatmaps. How can I keep the scale of the datasets the same?

Basic Code Used:

```
num_points = 100;
ke_pts = linspace(min(ke(filter)),max(ke(filter)),num_points);
ks_pts = linspace(min(ks(filter)),max(ks(filter)),num_points);
Pest = gridfit(ke(filter), ks(filter), S.totForce(filter), ke_pts, ks_pts);
imagesc(ke, ks, Pest)
axis xy
h = colorbar;
```

Here, filter is used to subset the dataset and consequently individually plot a heatmap of each subset.

I tried using caxis([min,max]), but it gives weird results, idk why.

Comment: Can you show the weird results you're talking about? Some sample data would also be nice to reproduce the problem on our end. thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Im missing the variables `filter`, `ke`, and `ks` to reproduce your example, but what I *think* you are asking is to avoid the automatic colorbar scaling for each `imagesc` plot.  If that is the case, the fourth argument to imagesc is the `clims` color bar limits.  Here is a working example:

```
rng(8675309) %// jenny number for consistency
subplot(1,2,1)
ke=linspace(0,1,100);
ks=linspace(0,1,100);
%// plot random numbers from 0-1 with a color bar from 0-2
imagesc(ke,ks,rand(100),[0,2])  
colorbar
subplot(1,2,2)
%// plot random numbers from 1-2 with a color bar from 0-2
imagesc(ke,ks,rand(100)+1,[0,2])
colorbar
```